# cv2.matchtemplate opencv inbuilt function takes undesired time for execution

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

import time

img = cv2.imread('rotate.png', 0)

template = cv2.imread('thresh_2.png', 0)

w, h = template.shape[::-1]

start = time.time();


res = cv2.matchTemplate( template, img, cv2.TM_CCORR)

stop = time.time();


print "TIME ",stop-start;

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc( res )

top_left = max_loc

bottom_right = ( top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h  )

cv2.rectangle( template, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2 )
```

Above code is working well but the time `cv2.matchtemplate` function takes is more than desired.

Time taken by the single instruction `cv2.matchtemplate` is 0.23 secs.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are that worried about performance, why write Python code in the first place ? Even though OpenCV internally uses C code, Python bindings are bound to be slower than the C or C++ API.

Comment: my whole application is based on python and this is the very basic template of one of the part of the application please give me the solution of this if possible

Comment: @Rucha can u share the images?